# Do high impedance pins have input capacitance?

Tags: digital-logic, capacitance, binary, high-impedance

I come from a software background and I'm trying to implement a simple counting circuit.  I am using [this SN74LV8154 binary counter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv8154.pdf) in a circuit which allows the outputs to be set to high impedance.

The design will have 4 counters connected together with the outputs all disabled and set to high impedance while counting.  After a short period of time, the clock input will be stopped and the count value from each counter will be read by enabling the outputs of each chip in turn.

I am concerned about the maximum count frequency in regards to load capacitance and asked [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254458/binary-counter-and-load-capacitance) question which really cleared up what load capacitance is.

My question is: **If the outputs of all counters are tied together while counting but all set to high impedance, does this mean the load capacitance of each counter while counting will be zero?**

The counter specifies an output capacitance (Co) but only for loads with GND or VCC.  As I understand high impedance, outputs are very very high impedance but not a true open circuit so wouldn't they provide a small input capacitance too?  As the outputs will be tied together 4x8=32 shared tracks per chip, even with a small input capacitance, I am worried this will significantly change the switching characteristics of the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there will be output capacitance of a few pF.

The 'typical' output capacitance is stated to be 5pF measured with a small test voltage near Vcc or 0V on the output. Because there are internal structures such as isolation and protection diodes that have a capacitance that varies with voltage there is not just one value, but you should be safe if you assume a maximum of maybe 10pF internal to the chip.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought the output capacitance is stated for when the output itself is GND or VCC.  So at high impedance do I assume typical '5pf' as well?  If that is the case, does this mean the capacitive loading of each counter with the outputs connected together to the other counters and set to high impedance will be 4 counters * 8 lines * 5pf = 160pf?

Comment: It assumed to be high-Z and externally driven to near GNzd/Vcc. Yes, but that 5pF is not guaranteed nor is it specified at mid voltages  so add some margin to be safe. Optimism is not a good thing in engineering.

Comment: I see - that makes sense.  It is strange then however that the datasheet specifies a maximum count frequency for the case when the load capacitance is 15pf.  If the high impedance outputs will always incur a typical of 5pf, and there are 8 outputs, even with the chip connected to nothing doesnt this mean the loading capacitance will be 5pf * 8 outputs = 40pf.  Doesnt that make a 15pf or less loading impossible?

Comment: Per output load capacitance. They also specify at 50pF.

Comment: yes - but my goal was to use the counter in the frequency range specified by 15pf or less loading.  I was trying to ensure my design met these requirements, but if the pins always produce a loading capacitance above this why list the 15pf?  and for that matter, how did they gain test data for 15pf or less?

Comment: If the chip is connected to nothing there is no load capacitance at all. Any test fixture will add a few pF- 15pF is probably reasonable for a small fan-out (output connected to one or two inputs or high-Z outputs and traces)

Comment: I see thank you.  So going back to my design, if I tie 4 chips output lines together, but all these lines are high impedance, even though they are high impedance this is not "nothing", so the loading will still be 'typical' 5pf per line, and should be expected to be well over 15pf?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will look for a different solution involving line buffers.